# Add new record var LINQ

Tags: c#, json, linq

I am trying to add a new record to the var "issue". I get a list of XXX from a SQL server DB and return in as follows for a jTable grid:

```
public dynamic XXXList(int CCC)
    {
        try
        {
            var issue = db.XXX.ToList().
                Select(c => new { DisplayText = c.AAA, Value = c.BBB, c.CCC}).
                Where(h => h.HHH == JJJ);

            return (new { Result = "OK", Options = issue });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return (new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message });
        }
    }
```

The function returns:

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "Result": "OK",
    "Options": [
        {
            "$id": "2",
            "DisplayText": "Food and Beverages",
            "Value": 4,
            "CCC": 4
        },
        {
            "$id": "3",
            "DisplayText": "Wrong software versions",
            "Value": 5,
            "CCC": 4
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I add another record to the issue var before returning it? 
Example:

```
{
    "DisplayText": "new display text",
    "Value": 5,
    "CCC": 4
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Here is my function after applying the answers:

```
public dynamic XXXList(int CCC)
{
    try
    {
        var newRecord = new[] { new { DisplayText = "None", Value = -1, CCC  = -1} };

        var issue = db.ProjectXXXs.Where(h => h.CCC == JJJ).Select(c => new { DisplayText = c.AAA, Value = c.BBB, c.CCC }).ToList().Concat(newRecord);

        return (new { Result = "OK", Options = issue });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return (new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message });
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for all the help.

Comment: Why are you calling `ToList()` *before* projection and filtering?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I moved it to after the where. What difference does it make if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: It will return every row from the table, create the object and then filter them in memory instead of adding a `where...` to the SQL query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concatenate any additional items:

```
var additional = new[] {new { DisplayText = ..., Value = ..., CCC = ... },
                        new { DisplayText = ..., Value = ..., CCC = ... }};

var issue = db.XXX.
    Where(h => h.HHH == JJJ).
    Select(c => new { DisplayText = c.AAA, Value = c.BBB, c.CCC}).
    ToList().
    Concat(additional);
```

*(EDIT: Credit for the reordering of Where, Select and ToList goes to James Curran.)*

Comment: Hmmm... I think C# will consider those three distinct anonomous classes, but the JSON serializer probably doesn't care.

Comment: @JamesCurran: C# will consider them to be of the *same* type, as long as you define the members in the same order and with the same type. Quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx): "*If two or more anonymous object initializers in an assembly specify a sequence of properties that are in the same order and that have the same names and types, the compiler treats the objects as instances of the same type. They share the same compiler-generated type information.*"

Answer (score 3):

Well first thing you want to do is move the ToList() to the end.  With the `ToList` where it was, you'd read every column from every record from the Database, build a list from that, and then search it.  With the ToList at the end, you send a query for just those columns of that record to the database, and then build a list from what comes back.  You'll also need to move the Where before the Select, so it applies to the XXX records and not the output from the select.

```
var issue = db.XXX
    .Where(h => h.HHH == JJJ)
    .Select(c => new { DisplayText = c.AAA, Value = c.BBB, c.CCC})
    .ToList();
```

From here the `Add` or `Concat` options suggested by other should work, however, you may have to use a named class instead of an anonomous one.

```
 class OptionValues
 {
      public string DisplayText {get; set;}
      public int  Value {get; set;}
      public int  CCC {get; set;}
 }

 // :
 // :
  .Select(c => new OptionValues {DisplayText = c.AAA, Value = c.BBB, CCC= c.CCC})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but can't you just write a line under var issue:

```
issue.Add(new { });
```

with the values that you want of course.

Comment: No it's not possible because `Where()` returns an `IEnumerable` which doesn't expose write methods.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation. I am still beginner in  the C# and i will take a closer look about this aspect.